# get data from an array of objects depending on a unique value of a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an API which gives me an array of objects, this is the response from the API

```
{
  data: [
    { order_status: "delivered", order_count: 2, order_amount: 1194 },
    { order_status: "processing", order_count: 1, order_amount: 597 },
  ]
}
```

Now I have to parse these data according to the `order_status` value of each object, means I will check for `order_status` value and put the corresponding data from that particular object in one column and so on. The expected view is this

[image]

my implementation code is

```
import Loader from "@components/common/Loader";
import { getBillInfo } from "@request/billing";
import { IBillInfo } from "models/billing";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { IoIosArrowDown } from "react-icons/io";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

export default function BillingInfo() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const shopSlug = router.query.slug as string;
  const { data, isSuccess, isLoading } = useQuery(
    [`bill-info`, shopSlug],
    () => getBillInfo(shopSlug),
    {
      enabled: Boolean(shopSlug),
      staleTime: Infinity,
    }
  );

  const billInfo: IBillInfo[] = isSuccess && data?.data.data;

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="mt-6">
      <div className="bg-white rounded shadow overflow-hidden">
        <div
          className="flex justify-between py-1 px-4 items-center cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50"
          onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
        >
          <h4 className="text-gray-600 mb-1 ml-1 mt-1 font-medium">
            Billing Information
          </h4>
          <div>
            <IoIosArrowDown size={20} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <CSSTransition
          in={toggle}
          timeout={100}
          classNames="slide-down"
          unmountOnExit
        >
          <div className="slide-down">
            {isLoading ? (
              <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-full">
                <Loader />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="grid grid-cols-5 gap-4 p-6">
                <div>
                  <h5 className="text-gray-500 capitalize">Total Orders</h5>
                  {billInfo &&
                  billInfo.some((el) => el.order_status === "total")
                    ? billInfo.map((order: IBillInfo, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <h3 className="font-medium text-xl">
                            ৳ {order.order_amount || "N/A"}
                          </h3>
                          <p className="text-gray-500">
                            Quantity:{" "}
                            <strong className="font-semibold text-black">
                              {order.order_count || "N/A"}
                            </strong>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      ))
                    : "N/A"}
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 className="text-gray-500 capitalize">Paid Orders</h5>
                  {billInfo && billInfo.some((el) => el.order_status === "paid")
                    ? billInfo.map((order: IBillInfo, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <h3 className="font-medium text-xl">
                            ৳ {order.order_amount || "N/A"}
                          </h3>
                          <p className="text-gray-500">
                            Quantity:{" "}
                            <strong className="font-semibold text-black">
                              {order.order_count || "N/A"}
                            </strong>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      ))
                    : "N/A"}
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 className="text-gray-500 capitalize">
                    Processing Orders
                  </h5>
                  {billInfo &&
                  billInfo.some((el) => el.order_status === "processing")
                    ? billInfo.map((order: IBillInfo, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <h3 className="font-medium text-xl">
                            ৳ {order.order_amount || "N/A"}
                          </h3>
                          <p className="text-gray-500">
                            Quantity:{" "}
                            <strong className="font-semibold text-black">
                              {order.order_count || "N/A"}
                            </strong>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      ))
                    : "N/A"}
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 className="text-gray-500 capitalize">Picked Orders</h5>
                  {billInfo &&
                  billInfo.some((el) => el.order_status === "picked")
                    ? billInfo.map((order: IBillInfo, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <h3 className="font-medium text-xl">
                            ৳ {order.order_amount || "N/A"}
                          </h3>
                          <p className="text-gray-500">
                            Quantity:{" "}
                            <strong className="font-semibold text-black">
                              {order.order_count || "N/A"}
                            </strong>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      ))
                    : "N/A"}
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 className="text-gray-500 capitalize">Refunded Orders</h5>
                  {billInfo &&
                  billInfo.some((el) => el.order_status === "refunded")
                    ? billInfo.map((order: IBillInfo, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <h3 className="font-medium text-xl">
                            ৳ {order.order_amount || "N/A"}
                          </h3>
                          <p className="text-gray-500">
                            Quantity:{" "}
                            <strong className="font-semibold text-black">
                              {order.order_count || "N/A"}
                            </strong>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      ))
                    : "N/A"}
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 className="text-gray-500 capitalize">Shipped Orders</h5>
                  {billInfo &&
                  billInfo.some((el) => el.order_status === "shipped")
                    ? billInfo.map((order: IBillInfo, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <h3 className="font-medium text-xl">
                            ৳ {order.order_amount || "N/A"}
                          </h3>
                          <p className="text-gray-500">
                            Quantity:{" "}
                            <strong className="font-semibold text-black">
                              {order.order_count || "N/A"}
                            </strong>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      ))
                    : "N/A"}
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 className="text-gray-500 capitalize">Delivered Orders</h5>
                  {billInfo &&
                  billInfo.some((el) => el.order_status === "delivered")
                    ? billInfo.map((order: IBillInfo, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                          <h3 className="font-medium text-xl">
                            ৳ {order.order_amount || "N/A"}
                          </h3>
                          <p className="text-gray-500">
                            Quantity:{" "}
                            <strong className="font-semibold text-black">
                              {order.order_count || "N/A"}
                            </strong>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      ))
                    : "N/A"}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But this implementation gives me this view

[image]

that means all the values from all the objects are shown in all of the columns but I want only the value corresponding the `order_status` in each of the respective columns. What am I doing wrong and what should I change in the code?

Comment: Your `some()` call simply checks if any record contains the relevant prop and then you `map()` the entire array. You should instead `filter()` the array for each type and then map those arrays per section. Also don't use `index` as key, it will only lead to headaches when the array order changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the object(s) that match your criteria prior to mapping them. Instead of calling `billInfo.map()` you need to call `billInfo.filter((e) => e.order_status === "your_status").map()`.